# javascript - getting value of select in a div

Tags: javascript, html, select

I'm trying to get the SELECT to give up it's value from this HTML which is forced upon me.

From the console it looks like I'm getting to the right place on the page, but when trying to check if I'm there the if = SELECT is not returning the correct thing...

Can anyone help...

Thanks and regards

```
<div id="Select1" class="dingbats_form_entry">
    <div class="dingbats_form_vertical_panel">
        <div>
            <div class="dingbats_form_label dingbats_form_label_top">Select1 </div>
            <div class="dingbats_form_field list_container" style="width: 100px;">
                <select class="gwt-ListBox dingbats_form_field_bottom" style="width: 135px;">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have my code as

```
<script>
function isRealValue(obj) {
    return obj && obj !== "null" && obj !== "undefined";
}

function getValue(ddl) {

    try {
        var obj = document.getElementById(ddl);
        if (isRealValue(obj)) {
            var lvl1 = obj.children;
            console.log(lvl1);
            var lvl2 = lvl1[0].children;
            console.log(lvl2);
            var lvl3 = lvl2[0].children;
            console.log(lvl3);
            var lvl4 = lvl3[1].children;
            console.log(lvl4);
            if (lvl4.tagName == 'SELECT') {
                alert("FOUND IT!!");
            }
            try {
                var val = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
            } catch (err) {
                window.alert("var val = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value " + err.message);
            }
            window.alert("myFunction: after Sel val:  Indx" + ddl + " " + val);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val;
        } else {
            window.alert("obj is not a real object: " + ddl + " " + obj);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        window.alert("var obj = document.getElementById(ddl)  " + err.message);
    }
}

if (document.getElementById("Select1")) {
    document.getElementById("Select1").addEventListener("change", function () {
        getValue("Select1");
    });
} else {
    window.alert("Select1 not found");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery? That would make this a LOT easier!

Comment: It seems like you know the ID of your parent element. So instead of going through each layer, use obj.getElementsByTagName("select"). This will give you a list of all select-elements in that node. If you only have one, you can access it via obj.getElementsByTagName("select")[0]

Comment: Yet to decide who gets the tick, they are all good suggestions so far...I'm only just learning java and javascript.  @Liath You think jQuery is easier? Not me...I do PL/1!

Comment: @SEan—jQuery doesn't make this easier. You can reduce the above to one line of code without jQuery, though common sense indicates 2 lines are more prudent.

Answer (score 2):

You're not far off. Use `getElementsByTagName()` to simplify it and add checks at each stage to avoid an unnecessary try/catch. Code below is untested.

```
function getValue(ddl) {
    var el = document.getElementById(ddl);
    if (el) {
        var selects = el.getElementsByTagName("select");
        if (selects.length > 0) {
            return selects[0];
            if (select.selectedIndex >= 0) {
                return select.value;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id attribute to your select tag.

```
<select class="gwt-ListBox dingbats_form_field_bottom" style="width: 135px;" id="myTag">
```

And to get the value do the following in JS:

```
var value = myTag.options[myTag.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Point is OP has no access to this HTML code if I understood.

Comment: Michael is correct, I don't have access to the HTML, that's why i tried to traverse the DIV

Comment: Why do people persist with the *selectedIndex* stuff? That hasn't been required by any browser since Netscape 5, yet it persists. Just use `selectElement.value`. And **never** suggest using IDs as global variables, that has been considered poor form for a decade.

Answer (score 0):

You should have :

```
if (lvl4[0].tagName == 'SELECT') {
    alert("FOUND IT!!");
}
```

And then :

```
var val = lvl4[0].options[lvl4[0].selectedIndex].value;
```

Since `obj` is your `div` not the `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('Select1');
var myVal = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value;
alert(myVal);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/92fu3Lx8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not to hard using the Selector API. Since you know the ID of the parent div (all elements support the selectors API) and seem to be wary of errors, consider:

```
var div = document.getElementById('Select1');
if (div) {
  var value = div.querySelector('select.dingbats_form_field_bottom').value;
}
```

which selects based on one of the class values, or you can use both:

```
var value = div.querySelector('select.gwt-ListBox.dingbats_form_field_bottom').value;
```

Regarding:

```
> return obj && obj !== "null" && obj !== "undefined";
```

If *obj* is either null or undefined, it will return false and the other two comparisons will never be tested. *getElementById* only ever returns either a single DOM element or *null*, so if it returns *null* only the first test will run and it will return false.

If the first test returns true (i.e. *getElementById* returns a DOM element), then the second two comparisons will always return true, since *getElementById* can never return a string, and certainly will never return either of the strings 'undefined' or 'null'.

So the function is well intended but not particularly useful.

In the *getValue* function, you should get rid of the *try..catch* blocks (they are almost never required in javascript, if you think you need them you are nearly always wrong). Consider instead:

```
function getValue(ddl) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(ddl);

    if (obj) {
      // do stuff with obj
    }
```

Regarding:

```
        try {
            var val = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
        } catch (err) {
```

that is completely useless. You'll only get to that line if *obj* is a DOM element. If you are uncertain if it's a select and want to get it's value you can do:

```
var val = obj.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select'? obj.value : null;
```

So if it's a select you'll get its value, which might be '' (empty string) if no option is selected, or a default of *null* if it wasn't a select. But if you use the selector API (or *getElementsByTagName* as suggested by others) you know that if you get an element, it must be a select.

Comment: I should have added there are many of these DIVs on the form...and they all look the same except for the ID=, apologies.