# How do you put the value of a select-element into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a function where you select a color of a shirt from a select-element and add it to the textarea when you press the button.

Also if anyone can give advice to do the same with a group of radio buttons, that would help a lot.

**JavaScript**

```
function addShirt() {
    buildStr += document.shirtInfo.color.value;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="shirtInfo">
    <h1>Shirts</h1>
    <select name="color">
        <option>White Shirt</option>
        <option>Black Shirt</option>
        <option>Grey Shirt</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="complete" value="Submit"   onclick="addShirt()"/>

    <textarea name="receipt" rows="10" cols="15"></textarea>
```

Comment: Consider adding actual values to your select options, like: `<option value="white">White Shirt</option>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405070/javascript-getting-value-of-select-in-a-div

Answer (score 1):

Please use IDs in your HTML.  Anyone trying to access your DOM will find it a lot easier to modify if they can just call an ID.

So, all you really want to do is add to the value of the textarea.

```
  // First, define the type of variable that you want (I chose an array)
  //  You don't have to, but it's easier for me to iterate over
var buildstr = [];

  //  I'm adding this event listener on the Javascript side 
  //  so it doesn't require you changing the HTML to modify it
document.shirtInfo.complete.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      //  Take the value of the dropdown and add it to the end of the array
    buildstr.push(document.shirtInfo.color.value);
      //  Then overwrite the value of the textarea with the array
    document.shirtInfo.receipt.value = buildstr;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getElementsByName` javascript function to access your textarea in javascript. Once you have access to the DOM element representing your textarea in javascript, you can use the `innerHTML` property to change its content.

```
function addShirt() { 
    document.getElementsByName("receipt")[0].innerHTML += document.shirtInfo.color.value; 
}
```

You should take note that `getElementsByName` returns an array. That is the reason why you have to take the first element of that array. You could also use `getElementById`, which returns only one element, after having added a unique `id` attribute to your textarea.

To make your results clearer, you might want to add a new line after each color you add :

```
        document.getElementsByName("receipt")[0].innerHTML += document.shirtInfo.color.value + "\n";
```